# Turning SQL into DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to turn this SQL into DQL with createQueryBuilder() and innerJoin() but confused a bit.

**ORM**

```
class Brands
{
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cars", mappedBy="brands")
     */
    private $cars;
}

class Cars
{
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brands", inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brands_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $brands;
}
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT
cars.id AS CarId,
cars.model AS CarModel,
brands.id AS BrandId,
brands.name AS BrandName
FROM cars
INNER JOIN brands ON brands.id = cars.brands_id
ORDER BY
cars.model ASC
AND
brands.name ASC
```

**REPO**

```
$repo = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('CarBrandBundle:Cars');

$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('c')
              ->innerJoin(.....)
```

Accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354401/using-join-in-symfony2-doctrine-sql) didn't look clean to me. I believe there is better way of doing it.

Comment: Could you post the entities mapping? To make sure the entities are related or not

Comment: hopefully the updated below answer help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what may help you:

```
$fields = array('c.id', 'c.model', 'b.id', 'b.name');
$repo = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('CarBrandBundle:Cars');

$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('c')
       ->select($fields)
       ->join('c.brands', 'b')
       ->addOrderBy('c.model', 'ASC')
       ->addOrderBy('b.name', 'ASC')
       ->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Good; happy to hear that