# JOIN DQL SYMFONY

Tags: symfony, dql

i want to count how many baby for a parent

```
 class abonnementRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function SumEnfantDQL($id)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $query->select('sum(o.id) AS somme');
        $query->from('AppBundle:enfant', 'o');
        $query->join('AppBundle:User','p')->where('p.id = :id');
        $rez = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
        return $rez;
    }
}
```

the entity enfant had matricul_prt and entity user had enfant_id and $id parameter is the parent id 
i don't know how it work with join or innerJoin .So what i want to do is

```
SELECT SUM(*)
FROM enfant e
WHERE e.matricul_prt = $id;
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Look this :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354401/using-join-in-symfony2-doctrine-sql

Comment: thanks for your reply  it's help but i don't know how i use it because i'm new with dql could you help me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should create a Repository class for AppBundle:enfant, this repo does not look like created fot 'enfant'.
Next the method should look like below, but only if there is valid association between 'enfant' and 'User'.

```
public function SumEnfant(int $id): int
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('e') <- alias for 'enfant'
        ->select('sum(e.id)') 
        ->join('e.user', 'u') <- join by entity property
        ->where('u.id = :id') <- condition for associated entity
        ->setParameter('id' , $id) <- parameter
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Try this, read doc once again and modify for your case.

Comment: thank you so much it's work but the data is return in array format and i want to render  the return result on my view what i should do thanks so much for your helping me